# Writing >Nul into a file

Tags: batch-file

I am currently very new to `.bat` and I was messing around trying to make one batch file write another one. So far I have been fine, but I have run into the error of not being able to put `>Nul` into the other batch file.

I'm trying to add a simple invisible delay, for example:

```
ECHO PING localhost -n 4 >NUl >> Test.bat
```

In that text, it usually treats the `>NUL` as part of the code and not something that will be written into the next file.

Sorry if my wording is confusing, I am just new and do not know the best way to explain this sort of thing.

Comment: You need to escape all problematic characters with a caret, `^`, _the more common being `|`, `<`, `&` and `>`_. Generally you sholud use the following methodology for single lines to be appended to an existing file, `>>"Test.bat" ECHO PING localhost -n 4 ^>NUL`, although there are better ways, if you're sending multiple commands exclusively to a new file. _(Any percent characters, `%` would be escaped with another percent character, i.e. `%%`.)_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The caret `^` is the Windows escape character so you would use:

```
>>test.bat echo ping localhost -n 4 ^>nul
```

Note that I've moved the actual redirection up to the front. This isn't technically necessary but it prevents extraneous spaces from appearing at the start or end of the line in your file (all spaces before and after the `>>test.bat` are placed in the file if it's not before the `echo`).